# JavaScript - What will be return when you window.getComputedStyle get property marginBlock & marginInline?

Tags: javascript, css

I was looking at the console.dir of an element and came across a number of properties that I was not aware of, so I wanted to get clarification on the margin-block & margin-Inline properties.

Will JavaScript marginBlock always return the margin-top & margin-bottom values and marginInline always return the margin-left & margin-right properties?

Thanks in advance – CES

margin: "10px 20px 30px 40px"
marginBlock: "10px 30px"
marginBlockEnd: "30px"
marginBlockStart: "10px"
marginBottom: "30px"
marginInline: "40px 20px"
marginInlineEnd: "20px"
marginInlineStart: "40px"
marginLeft: "40px"
marginRight: "20px"
marginTop: "10px"

Comment: Did you look it up? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline

Comment: Of course i did but im confused by "depending on the values defined for writing-mode, direction, and text-orientation"... marginBlock should always return top and bottom because I'm not aware of any languages that reverse to order and put the bottom  at the top. Where as some languages read left to right others right to left. BUT if you read my question can i be assured of ALWAYS getting TOP/BOTTOM and LEFT/ RIGHT Propertie Values!!

Comment: First, you never mentioned anything about writing mode direction in your question. Seems like a big assumption we would assume that. Second, it seems pretty easy to test, third, not sure why JavaScript not return what is in the CSS specification.